# How to fire a custom (python) service and continue in powershell using ansible?

Tags: python, powershell, ansible

I am trying to start a python service in a windows host using ansible. I have tried using both Start-Job and Start-Process as follows. But I am not able to get the exact results.

Using Start-Job

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Start-Process C:\Users\voiceqa\ansitest\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\voiceqa\ansitest\Scripts\run_wireshark_service.py -PassThru -RedirectStandardError C:\Users\voiceqa\error.txt -RedirectStandardOutput C:\Users\voiceqa\output.txt -NoNewWindow
```

The problem with this is as soon as ansible comes out of the session, Start-Job stops which inturn kills the process that it is running.

Using Start-Process

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "C:\Users\voiceqa\ansitest\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\voiceqa\ansitest\Scripts\run_wireshark_service.py" -WindowStyle Hidden -RedirectStandardError C:\Users\voiceqa\error.txt -RedirectStandardOutput C:\Users\voiceqa\output.txt -PassThru 

Start-Process C:\Users\voiceqa\ansitest\Scripts\python.exe -ArgumentList "C:\Users\voiceqa\ansitest\Scripts\run_wireshark_service.py" -WindowStyle Hidden -RedirectStandardError C:\Users\voiceqa\error.txt -RedirectStandardOutput C:\Users\voiceqa\output.txt -PassThru -UseNewEnvironment| Export-Clixml -Path C:\Users\voiceqa\wiresharkservice.xml

Start-Process C:\Users\voiceqa\ansitest\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\voiceqa\ansitest\Scripts\run_wireshark_service.py -PassThru -NoNewWindow
```

I have tried all these. All of these have same issues. Ansible is waiting for these commands to finish ( which it won't) as shown

[image: Here]
All I need is fire this python service and continue with rest of the work. How can I achieve this functionality? Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Simple `async` won't do here?

Comment: For windows async is not available for both script and raw tag.

Comment: How about adding `-AsJob` parameter to PowerShell `Start-Job` or `Invoke-Command`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky to do in the currently-released versions of Ansible. Even if you managed to background the tasks via `raw:` (which is possible with some hoop-jumping), WinRM won't let the command complete until all the processes exit (WinRM runs everything under a Windows job object). You have to escape the job.

Ansible 2.2 will have async, win_shell and win_command, but async isn't currently the right thing, since it leaves a watchdog process running that will kill the child process after the async timeout has elapsed. I've been testing a "breakaway" option for command/shell that will allow you to do what you're wanting (not sure if it'll be ready for primetime by 2.2 module freeze though).

If you're really running a service, I'd suggest setting it up as a Windows service (either directly, via sc, or using something like NSSM).

If that's a no-go, you can run background processes in the current version of Ansible (so long as you don't need access to stdin/stdout/stderr of the launched process) via `raw:` and WMI like this:

`raw: ([wmiclass]"Win32_Process").Create("myprocess.exe /option1 /option2")`